# how to use a PHP variable in SQL select statement

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database, select

I know this question was asked before. I have checked the old threads but without success. That's why i am posting it here again.

I have this php variable **$_POST["selected-Items"]** It's a result of the selected values in a drop down list in another page. For example if I selected country, order, date from the list then the result would be country,order,date

I want to extract from my SQL Server table the columns from this variable. I am using this query

```
$query = 'SELECT "'.$_POST['selected-Items'].'" FROM database.mytable';
```

Any suggestion please how to add the variable into the query in a correct way ? Thank you very much.

Comment: `$_POST["selected-Items"] = 'country,order,date'` Or `$_POST["selected-Items"] = array(country,order,date);`? what format of data is there? values coming into post as an array or as comma separated string?

Comment: `For example if I selected country, order` - `ORDER` stands to be reserved on sql-server.

Comment: don't use the var  directly .. this can cause sqlinjection .. check for your db driver and use  .. param binding ..  and for filter a value  in sql use where

Comment: @AlivetoDie  $_POST["selected-Items"] = 'country,order,date'  I just want to use the result after the Select. values coming into post as comma separated string

Comment: echo $query and see

Comment: My buddy bobby tables loves code like this. http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use double quotations `"` for column name!

```
SELECT column1, column2, ... FROM table_name
```

if `$_POST['selected-Items']` is an array you should implode it's items with `,`

```
$arr = ["value1", "value2", "value3"];
$string = implode(", ", $arr);
```

After using `implode` the `$string` will be like code below and you can use it for sql:

```
"value1, value2, value3"
```

your code must be like:

```
$query = 'SELECT ' . $_POST['selected-Items'] . ' FROM database.mytable';
```

After all, you should be aware of SQL injection when using this method!

Comment: Thank you one more time, this works very well on my example too.